# Javascript - Get words based on keypressed

Tags: javascript, keypress

Searching here, I found [this tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptkey2.shtml) and it is really helpful. I could easily do `document.onkeypress` to get the key pressed, and `String.fromCharCode()` to convert the keycode to a readable char. But I was wondering how can I be able to detect specific words?

Like:

```
var words; // something to store the latest 3 words for example

// then somehow concatenate each key pressed
// separating in the array based on the space key

var all = words[0]+" "+words[1]+" "+words[2];
var lastTwo = words[1]+" "+words[2];
if(all == "i love you"){
   alert("I love you too :)"); 
}else if(lastTwo = "screw you"){
   alert("You should not say something like this to me");
}
```

**EDIT:**  What I am really interested in is how can I concatenate the keys recursively?

Comment: Where are the word stored? If someone is typing in an input box, just grab the value of the box after every keypress.

Comment: Stored on the var itself. There is not input interaction with the user. Like the link I mentioned, you normally just type, and get an alert. I want to get the alert on that specific situation. I tried to keep doing the function recursively, but I did not end well when concatenating the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only problem is that I am editing the html file directly on the server with nano, so I just commit some mistakes that I could not recognize.

Basically doing:

```
var word = "";
function dump(e){
  var unicode = e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
  var actualkey = String.fromCharCode(unicode);
  word += actualkey;
  alert(word);
}
document.onkeypress = dump
```

I am able to see the keys concatenating which was my main problem. After that I will just adjust the values to an array and join them neatly like @Diodeus suggested.

Comment: I couldn't at the time. it blocks for a couple of days. I was just waiting.

Comment: No problem, I could accepted a little earlier cause I think it's two days to wait. But it is not my practice to enter here on Stack Overflow every single day. I am trying to achieve that, tough.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to build your array elements into a string:

```
var phrase = words.join(" ");
```

Then see what's in there.

```
if(phrase.indexOf('sandwiches')>-1) {
     alert("found sandwiches! let's eat.");
}
```

Comment: Understood. But I think I didn't express myself clearly. My problem is how to concatenate the keys to form the words.

Comment: I was kind of dumb (and lazy) to asked the question here before really looking into my problem. Thank you for you time anyway.